# Unable to select Terraform workspace in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy infrastructure in AWS using Azure Devops. I have a pipeline to deploy the infra into separate environments using Terraform. Using Terraform workspaces is how I have the back end infra being managed. I am getting an error selecting a workspace after initializing Terraform. Below is my `azure-pipelines.yml` file. I am utilizing the built in Tasks integration to integrate the steps for Terraform deployment. Any advice on how to structure the pipeline to get past this error would be helpful.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

stages:
  - stage: TerraformInstall
    displayName: Terraform
    jobs:
      - job: InstallTerraform
        displayName: Install Terraform
        steps:
          - task: charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform-installer.TerraformInstaller@0
  - stage: Init
    displayName: Init
    jobs:
      - job: init
        displayName: Terraform init
        steps:
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            inputs:
              provider: 'aws'
              command: 'init'

  - stage: DevStaging
    displayName: Push to Development / Staging
    jobs:
      - job: devstage
        displayName: Push to DevStaging
        steps:
          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
            inputs:
              provider: aws
              command: custom
              customCommand: 'workspace select devstage'
          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
            inputs:
              provider: aws
              command: apply
              commandOptions: '-var-file=devstage.tfvars -auto-approve'
```

**Error**

```
All other commands:
  console       Try Terraform expressions at an interactive command prompt
  fmt           Reformat your configuration in the standard style
  force-unlock  Release a stuck lock on the current workspace
  get           Install or upgrade remote Terraform modules
  graph         Generate a Graphviz graph of the steps in an operation
  import        Associate existing infrastructure with a Terraform resource
  login         Obtain and save credentials for a remote host
  logout        Remove locally-stored credentials for a remote host
  output        Show output values from your root module
  providers     Show the providers required for this configuration
  refresh       Update the state to match remote systems
  show          Show the current state or a saved plan
  state         Advanced state management
  taint         Mark a resource instance as not fully functional
  test          Experimental support for module integration testing
  untaint       Remove the 'tainted' state from a resource instance
  version       Show the current Terraform version
  workspace     Workspace management

Global options (use these before the subcommand, if any):
  -chdir=DIR    Switch to a different working directory before executing the
                given subcommand.
  -help         Show this help output, or the help for a specified subcommand.
  -version      An alias for the "version" subcommand.
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/terraform' failed with exit code 127
Finishing: TerraformTaskV3
```

Comment: "Exit code 127 means job's command can not be found or executed." Can you first try putting all the providers and commands (including the customCommand) in singe-quotes like you have on your `init` job?  if that doesn't work, try changing that `custom` to `workspace` and then below that commandOptions: 'select devstage'? Just spitballing...

Comment: actually, looking at their repo and readme, I don't think `workspace` is supported? https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-terraform/tree/main/Tasks/TerraformTask/TerraformTaskV3

Answer (score 1):

customCommand field only takes one keyword. in this case it would be 'workspace'
'select devstage' sholud be in the commandOptions

example:

```
          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
            inputs:
              provider: aws
              command: custom
              customCommand: 'workspace'
              commandOptions: 'select devstage'
```